# Excluding NULL values in a datatable query using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've got a line of code that will give me an array of meeting ID's (strings) that works just great when there are no nulls in the data table:

```
meetingIDs = meetingDateTable.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(x) x.ScheduleItemID).Distinct.ToArray()
```

I need to modify the line so it doesn't error, and excludes the null values from the result. here's what i've tried, but still get an error:

```
meetingIDs = meetingDateTable.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(x) x.ScheduleItemID).Where(Function(y) y <> String.Empty).Distinct.ToArray()
```

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Edit:
meetingDateTable is a strongly typed data table.
x.ScheduledItemID is a string that may be null.

Comment: Which is null?  `x` or `x.ScheduleItemID`? Is `x.ScheduleItemID` a string?

Comment: x.ScheduleItemID is a string that could be NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using both @DavidY and @DStanley answers this is the final solution:

```
    meetingIDs = meetingDateTable.AsEnumerable _ 
                                 .Where(Function(x) Not.IsScheduleItemIDNull).ToArray() _
                                 .Select(Function(y) y.ScheduleItemID).Distinct.ToArray()
```

maybe it can be written better?

Answer (score 0):

if `x.ScheduleItemID` is a string and could be null then a safer query would be

```
meetingIDs = meetingDateTable.AsEnumerable _
                             .Select(Function(x) x.ScheduleItemID) _
                             .Where(Function(y) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(y)) _
                             .Distinct.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out all of the null ScheduleItemID's first before you select.

```
meetingIDs = meetingDateTable.AsEnumerable. _
              Where(Function(id) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id.ScheduleItemID)). _
              Select(Function(y) y.ScheduleItemID)). _
              Distinct.ToArray()
```